# tmuxinator issue in executing multiple commands in panes

Tags: linux, zsh, tmux, tmuxinator

I am having trouble executing below tmuxinator config. When I run the configuration first letter of second command in panes section is removed. This is happening when I have to execute commands over a ssh session. Same behaviour is observed in executing commands in local but without any errors(first letter of second command is seen missing but gets executed in local).

Here is my sample config file

```
# /Users/ash/.config/tmuxinator/bst.yml

name: bassh
root: ~/

windows:
  - apps:
      layout: tiled
      panes:
        - app1:
          - ssh bst
          - ssh ash@198.174.145.1
```

Out put in tmux on running tmuxinator session for bst

```
~
➜ cd /Users/ash
sh bst
ssh ash@198.174.145.1

~
➜ ssh bst
sh ash@198.174.145.1
[ash@gzp-t2-v-server ~]$ sh ash@198.174.145.1
sh: ash@198.174.145.1: No such file or directory
[ash@gzp-t2-v-server ~]$
```

below are the versions I am using

```
➜ tmux -V
tmux 3.1b

➜ tmuxinator version
tmuxinator 2.0.1

➜ zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1
```

Comment: Which versions of zsh, tmux and tmuxinator are you using? Have you tried reducing this as much as possible in order to see if the problem is related to your shell/tmux/tmuxinator and not ssh? (e.g. https://gist.github.com/ethagnawl/160db3677674377abae58c9c2dd7684a)

Comment: Yes, I have tried when executing with `tmuxp` it is working well but not with `tmuxinator`